# Webform_onSubmit is not a function ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on a website located here:
http://www.travelanchevacations.com/mainlogin.aspx

When trying to login, I get this error in firebug:
WebForm_OnSubmit is not a function

It does the submit when you press enter bu when you click sign in, it throws the error.

I have no idea where this error is coming from or how to solve it. I've looked at the IIS settings and already set the .axd file extension to ASP.NET ISAPI according to this article http://forums.asp.net/t/1669216.aspx/1 but the error still is occuring.

Anyone have any ideas in order to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that `WebForm_OnSubmit()` doesn't exist, it is that the body of  `WebForm_OnSubmit()` is incorrect:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
null;if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
```

Take your extra `null;` out, and it will work better.

However, there are other issue on this site as well. Notably, if it is opened in IE, the following js error occurs (along with a few other cascading errors):

```
Line: 22
Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.
```

Comment: Genius! This site is a reproduction of another so I'm sure they're many many errors but I had to switch my ScriptManager to a ToolkitScriptManager.

Comment: Glad to help. Remember, if any answer solved or help you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer to let future visitors to the question know that this resolved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of case sensitivity.  The function on your page is defined as,

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit()
```

Your error message says,

```
Webform_onSubmit
```

`Webform_onSubmit` != `WebForm_OnSubmit`

Try changing your caller to match your functions case.

Comment: my bad, it was a typo on the question, the web error is WebForm_OnSubmit with the proper case. The OnSubmit is auto generated by the ASP.NET.

Comment: I updated the question to the proper-case, since OP lacked edit privs